# Text not staying in border?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for a school project and i'm trying to make the height of a border fit the size of the text. however, whenever i adjust the height the text doesn't go with it and i'm not sure how to fix this.
Code:

```css
#slidercompare {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  opacity: 87%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
}
#slidercompare {
  width: 355px;
  height: 40px; /* for some reason I can't adjust the height smaller than this or else the border goes through the text. */
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boardgames.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="slidercompare"><br>Chess.com (left) vs Video Chess (right)</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What result do you want to get? And why do you need the br tag inside the h1 tag?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `<br>` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It just removes the extra line within the h1 tag.

Comment: Oh my god i'm so dumb lol. I took my website and removed alot of it, but the break tag was to seperate another thing i had in there. lol thanks for pointing out the obvious

Comment: @GruelingPine185 and that's exactly the issue, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted `<br>` to `<h1>`. Used that to seperate a thing earlier i dont need to seperate now. So, removing the `<br>` tag fixed the issue.

Comment: this is not really an answer... :) use the comments section to add any

Comment: Edited it, should be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

May this be what you are trying to achieve?

```css
#slidercompare {
  font-size: 17px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  opacity: 87%;
}

#slidercompare {
  width: fit-content;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="slidercompare">Chess.com (left) vs Video Chess (right)</h1>
```

Comment: Please describe the changes you made.

Comment: In order to test this on my computer, I had to remove the `font-family: sans-serif; `I also removed the `position: absolute` to simplify the code as well as remove the unnecessary `hight: 40px;`. By default, the sizing matches the font size and fits the content.

Comment: Thank you, but this should be indicated on the solution (above the snippet), instead of text - *May this be what you are trying to achieve?*. This is necessary so that other people with a similar problem could understand the solution.